# pm2 kills everything and can not be restarted without a server reboot

Tags: node.js, pm2

[image]

Twice now all apps I have been running through pm2 has been stopped for no apparent reason to me. All apps where started with pm2 start app.js -n prettyname which works fine for a few days until this.

No I idea why it stops. But doing any pm2 command like the above in the screenshot, starting, restarting or stopping results in the same. [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon

Is there a way to restart the apps without restarting the server?

node 0.10.32
pm2 0.15.10

Comment: what does the *logs* say? Try `pm2 info` to see what happened to the apps

Comment: everything says: "[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon"

Answer (score 0):

Try below command to restart all pm2 apps,

```
pm2 restart all
```

Comment: everything says: "[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon"